# In ModelBuilder, can I reclassify the first set of the result of previous step?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I am trying to create this model and run it on multiple data sets. It's about interpolation of certain signals (electromagnetic data). So what I want to do is to get the first set of the interpolation results: the lowest numerical value set, my targeted set. Normally Arcmap will make it into  sets, so the first set can be accurate enough for my interpolation.

Here is a glance of my model.

[image: part of the model]

As a matter of fact, after I got the first set of the reclassify result, which is basically isolation, I want to get the centroid of that area.

But now the biggest problem seems to be: the reclassify option will always retain the value of last time. As shown below

[image: reclassify problem, value doesn't change, it retains the old value]

Comment: Have you looked into [Calculate Value](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-value.htm)? You can use this to populate values for the reclassification parameter.

Comment: Please do not include a statement of urgency or unnecessary thanks within your question.  http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/q/3672/115